# Optirun Bumblebee crash

Tags: bumblebee

Whenever I try to run some programs under bumblebee with optirun they crash before displaying any window. I particularly try to run supermeatboy  because it doesn't support intel cards, but with bumblebee it doesn't get even to displaying a window unlike the intel one and crashes prematurely. I've attached the xorg log. http://paste.pocoo.org/show/540542/

Thanks in advance, 
Nikita.

Comment: Bumblebee 3.0 does not use Xorg.8.log or bumblebee.log anymore. Please attach `/var/log/syslog` instead.

Comment: added the syslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup looks fine. I guess that you are affected by [issue 42: [VGL] ERROR: Could not open display :8 if a program forks and exits optirun](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/42).

This bug occurs when running an application with `optirun` which detaches. Workaround: open a shell and then run the program:

```
optirun bash
yourprogram
```

Comment: Tried it. Now I get a "Segementation Fault" in console. This is the log: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/540555/

Comment: What program are you trying to run? Do you get other errors in the console? If it's a 32-bit program, install the `virtualgl-libs:i386` package.

Comment: As mentioned in the question it's supermeatboy. Apart from the segmentation fault nothing and virtualgl appear to be at the latest version

Comment: Is there an entry in `dmesg` when the program segfaults?

Comment: This http://paste.pocoo.org/show/540581/

Comment: Try a debugger, after `optirun bash`, run `gdb yourprogram`. In the gdb shell, execute `run` and after the crash `bt`. To quit it, run `quit` (add the output to your question or pastebin).

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/540623/ I should get a loyal pastebin costumer badge after this :D.

Comment: Please install `virtualgl-libs-dbg:i386` and generate a new backtrace.

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/541028/ Sorry for the late response.

Comment: It looks like a bug in Virtual GL. From what I've read, it's because an OpenGL context was not correctly established. What you can do about it? At most reporting it to the virtualgl bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
optirun bash
sudo ./SuperMeatBoy
```

Using `sudo` helped me to avoid `Segmentation fault`

Comment: This is wrong, `sudo` just makes `optirun` useless and omitting `optirun` has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Using `primusrun` instead of `optirun` solves this problem.

[Primus](https://github.com/amonakov/primus) is a different bumblebee backend with better performance (less overhead) and less power usage (second GPU only used for OpenGL parts of the program).

You install primus with `sudo aptitude install primus` and run it with:

```
primusrun your_cool_program
```

This is far easier to use in scripts than the optirun workarounds.